# Python xml replace value from one string

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I would like to do simple edit in xml with python.

I have following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<MoneyData ICAgendy="50232240" KodAgendy="" HospRokOd="2016-01-01" HospRokDo="2016-12-31" description="zásoby" ExpZkratka="_ZAS" ExpDate="2016-09-07" ExpTime="22:42:00" VyberZaznamu="0"><SeznamZasoba><Zasoba><konfigurace><Druh_zas>Z</Druh_zas><SDPH_Nakup>20</SDPH_Nakup><SDPH_Prod>20</SDPH_Prod><Ev_Min>0</Ev_Min><Ev_Max>0</Ev_Max><Minimum>0</Minimum><Maximum>0</Maximum></konfigurace><StavZasoby><Zasoba>27</Zasoba><Rezervace>0</Rezervace>
<Objednano>0</Objednano></StavZasoby><Nak_Cena>0.5687</Nak_Cena><Posl_N_Cen>0.552</Posl_N_Cen><Posl_Nak>2016-08-17</Posl_Nak><Posl_Prod>2016-08-25</Posl_Prod><SklUcet>000000</SklUcet><WWWPopis>Vrecko je zhotovené zo 100% bavlny. Možno ho ďalej dekorovať farbami na textil, batikovaním, rôznymi aplikáciami a pod.</WWWPopis><Vyrobce>Pentart</Vyrobce><Sleva>0</Sleva><Novinka>0</Novinka><Pripravuje>0</Pripravuje><Vyprodej>0</Vyprodej><ZakazProde>0</ZakazProde><VSleva>0</VSleva><VAkce>0</VAkce>
<VNovinka>0</VNovinka><PrvaStrana>0</PrvaStrana><UcPohyb><UcProdejk>000000</UcProdejk><UcPrijemk>000000</UcPrijemk><UcVydejky>000000</UcVydejky><UcVyrobky>000000</UcVyrobky><UcVDodLst>000000</UcVDodLst><UcPDodLst>000000</UcPDodLst><UcManko>000000</UcManko><UcPreb>000000</UcPreb></UcPohyb><UcVyrobkV>000000</UcVyrobkV><MnInv>0</MnInv><eshop><IN_Export>6</IN_Export><IN_Changed>0</IN_Changed><CisKarty>1754</CisKarty><CisSkladu>2</CisSkladu><eSkup><ID>131</ID><Name>Textilné výrobky {030403}</Name><Descript>131_Textilné výrobky {030403}</Descript><Poznamka></Poznamka><Changed>0</Changed>
<Public>1</Public><Parent><ID>104</ID><Name>Predmety na dekorovanie {030400}</Name><Descript>104_Predmety na dekorovanie {030400}</Descript><Poznamka></Poznamka><Changed>0</Changed><Parent><ID>60</ID><Name>Pomôcky{030000}</Name><Descript>60_Pomôcky{030000}</Descript><Poznamka></Poznamka><Changed>0</Changed><Parent><ID>10</ID><Name>Všetky zásoby</Name><Descript></Descript><Poznamka></Poznamka><Changed>0</Changed></Parent></Parent></Parent></eSkup></eshop><KmKarta><Popis>Vrecko so šnúrkou, 24 x 30 cm</Popis><Zkrat>Malé vrecko so šnúrk</Zkrat><MJ>ks</MJ><GUID>{AC0119E4-7248-453E-A16E-5576B8E71951}</GUID>
<Katalog>727</Katalog><TypZarDoby>N</TypZarDoby><ZarDoba>0</ZarDoba><DesMist>0</DesMist><Obrazek>P:\DPT017.jpg</Obrazek><Pozn1>&lt;p&gt;Rozmery rámu: 26,5 cm x 26 cm.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Rozmery fotografie: 8,5 cm x 13,5 cm.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Fotografia sa skladá medzi sklenené tabule z boku.&lt;/p&gt;</Pozn1><Hmotnost>0</Hmotnost><Objem>0</Objem><TypKarty>jednoducha</TypKarty></KmKarta><Sklad><Nazev>Pentart</Nazev><KodSkladu>pentart</KodSkladu><GUID>{6B9261FD-A281-4F33-80FA-5C410283C788}</GUID><CenikSklad>0</CenikSklad></Sklad><Skupina><Zkratka>NEZARADENÉ</Zkratka><Nazev>Nezaradené</Nazev></Skupina><PC>
<SDPH>1</SDPH><Zaok>N</Zaok><ZpusobZao>M</ZpusobZao><Mena><Kod></Kod></Mena><VypPrCeny>V</VypPrCeny><VychA>Z</VychA><ZpusobZmA>S</ZpusobZmA><VychB>1</VychB><ZpusobZmB>S</ZpusobZmB><Cena1><Cena>1.34</Cena><Sleva>15</Sleva></Cena1><Cena2><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena2><Cena3><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena3><Cena4><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena4><Cena5><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena5></PC><PC><Hladina><Zkrat>VO</Zkrat></Hladina><SDPH>1</SDPH><Zaok>H</Zaok><ZpusobZao>M</ZpusobZao><Mena><Kod></Kod></Mena><VypPrCeny>V</VypPrCeny><VychA>Z</VychA><ZpusobZmA>S</ZpusobZmA><VychB>1</VychB><ZpusobZmB>S</ZpusobZmB><Cena1><Cena>1.25</Cena><Sleva>7</Sleva></Cena1><Cena2><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena2><Cena3><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena3><Cena4><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena4><Cena5><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena5></PC><PC><Hladina><Zkrat>VOP</Zkrat></Hladina><SDPH>1</SDPH><Zaok>H</Zaok><ZpusobZao>M</ZpusobZao><Mena><Kod></Kod></Mena><VypPrCeny>V</VypPrCeny><VychA>Z</VychA><ZpusobZmA>S</ZpusobZmA><VychB>1</VychB><ZpusobZmB>S</ZpusobZmB><Cena1><Cena>1.25</Cena><Sleva>7</Sleva></Cena1><Cena2><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena2><Cena3><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena3><Cena4><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena4><Cena5><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena5></PC><PC><Hladina><Zkrat>VOC</Zkrat></Hladina><SDPH>0</SDPH><Zaok>N</Zaok><ZpusobZao>M</ZpusobZao><Mena><Kod></Kod></Mena><VypPrCeny>C</VypPrCeny><VychA>N</VychA><ZpusobZmA>M</ZpusobZmA><VychB>Z</VychB><ZpusobZmB>S</ZpusobZmB><Cena1><Cena>0.84</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena1><Cena2><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena2><Cena3><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena3><Cena4><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena4><Cena5><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena5></PC><PC><Hladina><Zkrat>VOS</Zkrat></Hladina><SDPH>0</SDPH><Zaok>H</Zaok><ZpusobZao>M</ZpusobZao><Mena><Kod></Kod></Mena><VypPrCeny>V</VypPrCeny><VychA></VychA><ZpusobZmA></ZpusobZmA><VychB></VychB><ZpusobZmB></ZpusobZmB><Cena1><Cena>0.95</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena1><Cena2><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena>
<Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena2><Cena3><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena3><Cena4><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena4><Cena5><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena5></PC></Zasoba></SeznamZasoba></MoneyData>
```

And what I need is to copy and replace value e.g. 0.84 from:

```
<PC><Hladina><Zkrat>VOC</Zkrat></Hladina><SDPH>0</SDPH><Zaok>N</Zaok><ZpusobZao>M</ZpusobZao><Mena><Kod></Kod></Mena><VypPrCeny>C</VypPrCeny><VychA>N</VychA><ZpusobZmA>M</ZpusobZmA><VychB>Z</VychB><ZpusobZmB>S</ZpusobZmB>
<Cena1><Cena>0.84</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena1><Cena2><Limit>0</Limit>
<Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena2><Cena3><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena>
<Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena3><Cena4><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva>
</Cena4><Cena5><Limit>0</Limit><Cena>0</Cena><Sleva>0</Sleva></Cena5></PC>
```

Info string: `<Nak_Cena>0.5687</Nak_Cena>`

Could you please help me how to do so?

Thank you.

PS: sorry if my question is not formatted correctly.

Filip

Comment: not much, just beginning and end:

#import os.path
#if not os.path.exists("/volume1/creActive/Prevod_skladu/opravene.xml"):

from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse("/volume1/creActive/BUSINESS/Nakupne_ceny/zasoba.xml")

for node in tree.findall(“.//Cena”):
            
tree.write('/volume1/creActive/Prevod_skladu/opravene.xml',encoding="windows-1250")

Comment: i'll suggest you need to use `root = tree.getroot()`, then look for your tag by name as `node = root.find(your_element_tagname)`, then change the value by `node.text = "..."`

Comment: The problem is, that there is tag name <Cena>0.84</Cena> used more than one time and I need the one wich is used in <PC> where <Hladina><Zkrat>VOC</Zkrat>. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: your can resolve by using relative path or if you use `lxml`, then xpath to achieve that easily

Comment: Ok, I am the very new one in this, not a programmer, could you maybe help me and write down and example how is should look like? I need to create this script to make easier one process in my company :)

Comment: I'm sorry although I can provide an answer but that doesn't fit the purpose of SO, you need to come up with your own solution and what doesn't work, and we provide insight and correct your mistake or confusion.

Comment: @FilipKotian: The XML file is pretty large and badly formatted for humans to read. Please try to trim it down as much as possible. See [mcve]. And what is "Info string"?